# I cant build my project with brunch.io

Tags: github, ecmascript-6

this is my first question on StackOverflow so excited  !!!
So this morning  i wanted to  make an es6 app  to train myself with es6;

but when i  wrote the brunch command : brunch new -s es6  on my folder

I am Getting  a wierd thing like :

(node:2122) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

where did i go wrong ?

the full error is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe2BB.png)

Comment: Please paste the content of the error message into your question and not as an external image link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install git on your computer and make sure git command will work on you CMD。open CMD and type `git` make sure no error occur.

if you didnt install git ,go the the site below to download git.
[git download page](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

if you using windwos. git command might not work on the CMD. open the Git Bash instead.

Comment: I do not have any problem with git it  is well installed on my computer;  I will remake the project from scratch and see if everything works fine